# Very huge executables size when compiling c++ using g++ and Makefile

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

while using g++ (version 4.9.2) from MinGW provided with Code::Blocks IDE, I am getting incredibly huge .exe files, going up to 1000KB for a "Hello, World!" program. I use exactly the same compiling options as like it would be compiled from "inside" of Code::Blocks (mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -g hello.cpp -o hello.exe, anyway, i just copy it from the Code::Blocks log window), but unlike that way, which produced about 70KB output for Debug target and 50KB for Release, this keeps on making incredibly large output.

Did anyone else meet a similar issue?

[EDIT] My project (created only for testing Makefiles purposes) consists on two files, main.cpp and fun.cpp (no headers). Here is main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void fun(void);

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello Make!"<<endl;
    fun();
    return 0;
}
```

and here is fun.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void fun()
{
    cout<<"Hello from The Module!"<<endl;
}
```

And finally, this is my Makefile:

```
CC = mingw32-g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -Os -lto


all: main.o fun.o
    ${CC} -o hello.exe $^

relink:
    mingw32-g++ -o hello.exe hello.o fun.o

main.o: main.cpp
    mingw32-g++ ${CFLAGS} -c main.cpp -o $@

fun.o: fun.cpp
    mingw32-g++ ${CFLAGS} -c fun.cpp -o $@

clean:
    del *.o
```

When compiling this "project" under Code::Blocks I get the following
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThBQA.png)

When using Makefile, the output file is 1024KB large:
([print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duh69.png))

Comment: Have you tried using the `strip` utility from binutils?  It should be included in your toolchain.  Is the large executable statically linked to libstdc++?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can check out what is in an obj or exe file with `objdump`. For example, with `objdump -x hello.exe`, you can check out the various sections of an exe (you'll find the size of each section), with `objdump -d hello.exe` you can run a disassembler on hello.exe.

Answer (score 3):

Debug builds will usually be larger than optimized (aka "release") ones. Try adding `-O2` or `-O3` to your build options (or `-Os` to specifically optimize for size).

Also, if you don't need the debug symbols in a release build then remove `-g` (or remove them afterwards with the `strip` command).

Also; compiling with Link-Time Optimization can sometimes yield a size reduction (in addition to a performance improvement) - for that use the `-lto` option (in addition to one of the `-O` options).

The above should give you a significant size reduction.

See the gcc manual for more details on the options.

Comment: g++ options, even -Os didn't help at all (Size reduced 0.5%). What i actually try to figure out is why the same compiler with the same options, same optimization flags, with same source file, used from "outside" of Code::Blocks and "inside" of it, gives me different results...

Comment: @Michal you may be *compiling* it the same way but are you also *linking* it the same way? Static vs dynamically linked runtime library perhaps?

Comment: I just copy to my Makefile (to _all_ target) the following line from Code::Blocks compile log window: mingw32-g++.exe  -o main.o foo.o, to be sure the linking goes the same way. Is there a way to tell which libraries are statically linked by gcc?

Comment: @Michal post a [mcve] that we can use to try and replicate your results.

Comment: In case you didn't obtain notification, I've just posted it in a answer below

Comment: @Michal - you shouldn't post that as an answer (it is not one). You should edit your original question instead and add it there.

Comment: Sorry, new in Stack Overflow, fix it in a while

Comment: @Michal and please don't link to stuff off-site. *Everything* related to the question should be *in* the question - as *text*.